# How to replace numbers with text in R

Tags: r, if-statement

I am new to using R and I am encountering a really annoying roadblock.

I am trying to use a dataset and convert all 0's to a value of "Not_Eaten' and all 1's to a value of Eaten.

I am using this statement

```
attach(data)
Eaten <- ifelse(Eaten==0, "Not_Eaten",'Eaten')
```

but the datasheet does not update and the Eaten column is still populated with 0's and 1's.

Can someone please point out what I am doing wrong here?

If it helps, the class is integer and not numeric for some reason.

Comment: Try `data$Eaten <- ifelse(data$Eaten==0, "Not_Eaten",'Eaten')`

Comment: You should avoid using `attach()`. It doesn't update the underlying data frame. If you modify values, it will just make copies in the global environment. Use something like `transform()` or `dplyr::mutate()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
data$Eaten <- ifelse(data$Eaten == 0, "Not_Eaten", 'Eaten')
```

Or:

```
data$Eaten <- ifelse(data['Eaten'] == 0, "Not_Eaten", 'Eaten')
```

Comment: This works. So I guess the fact that I was using attach was the issue